# Help w/ Duke Fishron

Tags: terraria

I really need some good tips for Duke Fishron. I can never seem to kill him. I am using the chlorophyte shot bow with holy arrows. I also have Vampire knives just in case. I am using ironskin, pumpkin pie, swiftness, and some others. What am i missing here?

Comment: I understand you are frustrated, but this site is not a forum. This is too broad of a question to ask here. Often times, the questions here require a definitive answer, not a collection of opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Set up campfires and a honey pool to regenerate health. Also get a summoning items like minions and turrets for auto damage. Other that that just make sure you have the best gear you can have for your class. Check the forums if you need help with classes. And if you haven't already build over the ocean so you have a flat place to battle.

Also like Diriector_Doc said maybe go to a forum of some sort to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: Nvm I just beat him